# Xbox Music app "Sorry, we can't play this file on your phone" Error codes: C10103E8 or 800706BF

Tags: xbox-music

I'm getting error codes C10103E8 or 800706BF when attempting to play tracks on my Nokia Lumia 620 (OS version 8.0.10328.78).

All types of tracks are failing to play: tracks downloaded with Xbox Music Pass, locally owned MP3s copied to SD card, tracks streamed using Xbox Music pass.

Please help it's driving me crazy not to mention wasting my £9 / month subscription.

Comment: Have you tried resetting your phone?  0x800706BF indicates an RPC failure, which seems to indicate some problem launching code needed to play MP3s.

Comment: Yes, I've tried a soft and hard reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading to WP8.1, I no longer have these issues.

Comment: That's good to hear - don't forget to flag this as the accepted solution - you can always accept a better answer later, if it comes along.

Comment: I thought the "Answer your own question" button would mark it as the answer automatically. Anyhow, thanks for the reminder.